# C# SqlConnection.BeginDbTransaction times out

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, timeout, sqlclient

I have a .NET Core 3 web application that works with SQL Server. A while ago I started to get Timeout errors like

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): Unknown error 258
```

The error appears on the call to beginning transaction. Full stacktrace:

```
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): Unknown error 258
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginSqlTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName, Boolean shouldReconnect)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.BeginDbTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel isolationLevel, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

System.Data.SqlClient version is 4.7.0

How do I fix it? Can I set some kind of timeout for this operation to be a little bigger? Could there be any problem with our network?
Maybe upgrade to .NET 6 can resolve the problem, but I don't see how since System.Data.SqlClient is the same on .NET Core 3 and .NET 6.

PS. We also had the same problem on opening the connection, but looks like this got fixed via 'Timeout' setting in the ConnectionString.

Comment: Methinks the server is overloaded and for whatever reason can't find a spare thread.

Comment: @Charlieface do you mean the database or the web application server?

Comment: The database server. You might want to look at wait stats and see what comes up, I'm guessing it's THREADPOOL. see https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/01/network-issue-threadpool-waits/ and https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you! I'll look these articles up and then come back with information. Thank you once again.